# Nested RecyclerView with wrap_content and without nested scrolling

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout, android-glide

Is it possible to have a nested `RecyclerView`s with following criterias?

1. The outer `RecyclerView` is attached programmatically near the top of the  view hierarchy of the `Activity`
2. The outer `RecyclerView` is scrollable
3. The inner `RecyclerView` lives inside a custom view which is also attached programatically
4. The inner `RecyclerView`  has a vertical `GridLayout` with `ImageView`s
5. The inner `RecyclerView` has width `match_parent` and height `wrap_content`
6. The inner `RecyclerView` is **not scrollable**
7. The inner `RecyclerView` can displays all it's elements by scrolling the outer `RecyclerView`
8. The items inside the `RecyclerView` are recycled correctly

I am trying to build this but the last two criterias are not satisfied. If I have more than 30 Images (GridLayout has 3 columens, so I have minimum 10 rows) further images are not displayed. And if I open the HierarchyViewer I see that the RecyclerView contains all the inner ViewHolders so nothing is recycled, even if i scroll down.

Furthermore I have questions towards the Images within the grid of the `RecyclerView`.  want to calculate their width dynamically and the images are loaded with [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) Library. I make a request to a server which gives me the images in the right width, but the surrounding `ImageView`a have 2 dp less than the images themselves. I have a grid spacing of 8dp. I calculate the width of the images(to be requested) with this formula:

```
imageWidth = (screenWidth - 2 * horizontalActivityPadding - 2 * spacing) / 3;
```

This should work for a `GridLayout` with 3 columns. But then the imageWidth has 90dp and the `ImageView`'s width becomes 88dp. This is because I get a spacing after the 3rd column. But I only calculated twice the spacing so I expect to have this spacing only

- between the 1st and the 2nd column
- and between the 2nd and the 3rd column
- but **not** after the 3rd column

What may be the reasons for

1. my `RecyclerView` problem?
2. my image spacing problem?

Comment: Hm..I'm a little bit confused while reading the problem. Why do you need a RecyclerView when it should not be scrollable? Won't it be better if you use view type and RecyclerView's holder and make just a single RecyclerView with different view types?

About GridLayout.. as far as I know it is better avoid using it. It's better to build your view using RelativeLayout (you can easily achieve grid with it)

Comment: @KamenStoykov I know this is confusing because it's a bit complicated. The inner ``RecyclerView`` shall not be scrollable cause I have a ``CollapsingToolbarLayout`` and it wouldn't be collapsing anymore if I scroll the inner ``RecyclerView``. I've already seen a ``RecyclerView`` with different view types but I think this is a bit of a dirty architecture. Why do you think I shall avoid ``GridLayout``? Are there any reasons? I want to have a several number of columns depending on the screen width displaying the images. And I don't know how to achieve this without ``GridLayout``. Maybe you know?

Comment: GridLayout is old widget and as I know its performance is not so good, but I can agree with you that this is not the main concern now. Really do not know what else to advice you. In your cases I was always using view types :)

Comment: @unlimited101 I know the post if a bit old, but were you able to resolve this situation of yours. I have a similar need in which I render a vertical recyclerview (either with LinearLayoutManager or GridlayoutManager) inside another vertical recyclerview. The inner RV does not recycle views at all, causing memory and performance issues when the number of rows goes in the hundreds, for obvious reasons. Was wondering what approach you ended up with? Thanks!